# Use simple boolean value as custom validator

Tags: angular

I am experimenting with form validation in Angular 4 and I am a bit stuck with implementing a custom validator.

Here is my form group declaration:

```
    this.signupForm = fb.group({
        'username': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(21)])],
        'email': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.email, Validators.required])],
        'password': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])]
    });
```

Now I have a function that will get triggered each time the 'username' control value changes to query my DB and sets the value of a boolean 'userExists' to true if the user already exists and to false otherwise. I can't seem to combine the regular Validators with this simple boolean value. 
I have tried in my html to do the following:

```
                <input type="text" [formControl]="signupForm.controls['username']" name="username" matInput placeholder="Username" (ngModelChange)="checkUsername($event)">
                <mat-error *ngIf="userExists || !signupForm.controls['username'].valid">
                    Error
                </mat-error>
```

I have inspected the value of userExists and this works fine. The problem is that it seems that the mat-error will only appear based on the Validators declared, not taking into account anything else. Funny thing is that if you remove the *ngIf, the validations rules will still be respected and mat-error will appear only in case of invalid conditions (which I didn't know about - must be something related to Material).

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: How does your `checkUsername` actually look like?

Comment: Rather good. The `checkUsername` is working fine, and was working way before I decided to start using validator. If I just go `{{userExists}}` I get the correct result. I just can't use this result in `mat-error` if I implement validators.

Comment: Still asking how does it look like? :D I mean the code.